# Fetching Dynamic buttons from database takes too long

Tags: c#, mysql, database, multithreading

I'm developing a POS windows application, and i want it to be fast, but when i fetch the data from MySql, it takes like 5 seconds to fetch 100 tables of a restaurant.
Can anyone here tell me is there a way to load the data from database when application starts up, so i can call them later without waiting every time when i open the Table form ?

here is a code example :

```
FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tables ORDER BY number_of_table", conn);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(241, 234, 182);
                b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                b.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                b.Tag = dr[2].ToString();
                b.Click += new EventHandler(OpenTavolina);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database is very  unlikely to have a performance issue with loading 100 records that only have three columns.

Instead the issue is going to be the 100 separate calls to add child controls to your layout panel. Each time you add a new child it will perform a layout processing cycle.

To get around this you can instruct the control to suspend processing of layout until you have finished adding the child controls. So before your **foreach** loop...

```
floatLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
```

...and then after the **foreach** loop allow layout processing again...

```
floatLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

Then your only taking the layout processing hit the once. If you look in the generated code for any Form that has layout controls, you will see it auto generates these calls at the start and end of the code.

Comment: this one seems like a better solution , the first time loads slower, but when i enter the form next time it loads it faster, about 2 seconds.
But, its not quite perfect, im trying to find  a better solution i read a bit for Multithreading but i thing thats not the case in my application, cuz this form is fetching only this query and nothing more ...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's the sql query taking 5 seconds?  If so, you have a serious database issue, you need to clean up joins and add indexes, or possibly have a bad internet connection.  I suspect the whole operation from start to drawing finish is 5 seconds.  If you can break apart the data request and button drawing into two different functions, you can time them.

Most likely, its the 100 reflow, repaint you are performing.

If the bottleneck is the UI, try setting the flow update panel visible = false before adding the buttons, set it back to visible = true afterward.

-- EDIT 1 after discovering issue is with reflow :

You can create a static class for a cache.

for instance...

```
public static class DataManager
{   
   public static List<Button> FormButtons {get; set;}

   static DataManager()
   {
      FormButtons = new List<Button>();
   }

   public static void LoadButtonsOnce()
   {
          //build buttons from database and perform a...

          FormButtons.Add(newButton) 
   }

}
```

now you can access DataManager.FormButtons anywhere you want...

Keep in mind, this still won't fix the problem with repaint/reflow.  You will still need to perform the .visible hack to fix that.

Comment: You are right, its not the database problem , its when i create the dynamic buttons, I just tested it.
Is there a way, to create these buttons when the application starts up, and than just call them in Table form ?

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is your query itself.  You are doing a `select * from`...  Never do a `select *`, but rather optimize your query by only returning the specific columns you need. For instance, if dr[1] is a field named 'name_of_table' and dr[2] is a field named, 'number_of_table', then your query should only be, `select name_of_table, number_of_table`...

As a side note, never access a field in your c# code like, `dr[1]`.  That makes it hard for other developers to come in and work on your code.  Also, if another developer changes the query, then the index where the column exists will change.  Always use the column name, like so, `dr["name_of_table"]`.  This way, no matter where the field exists in the 'select', it won't fail.

Comment: My table is containing 3 colums , and all those 3 colums i need, thats why i select * from table.
But when the restaurant has 100 tables than it takes longer to create those button tables to the form...

Comment: Regardless, you should never use select *.